# Can two characters mark the same enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

Can my friend, who is a swordmage, and I, who am a battlemind, both have the same enemy marked at the same time?

I tried to read the rules and look up the answer but I am pretty new to D&D.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, a creature can only be marked by one opponent at a time.**

From the Rules Compendium, p232 (*emphasis mine*):

> #### Marked
>
> - The creature takes a -2 penalty to attack rolls for any attack that doesn't include the marking creature as a target.
> - *A creature can be subjected to only one mark at a time, and a new mark supersedes an old one.*
> - A mark ends immediately when its creator dies or falls unconscious.

A creature can only be marked by one person at a time. When a 2<sup>nd</sup> person marks the creature, the 1<sup>st</sup> person's mark is removed.